# Как мне сделать код более гуманным?

Tags: php

```
if($msg == 'пример сообщения') {
    if($user->messages == 0) {
        echo "нет сообщений";
    } else {
        $chance = mt_rand(1,3);
        if($rand == 1) {
            echo "первое событие";
        } else if($chance == 2) {
            echo "второе событие";
        } else if($chance == 3) {
            echo "третье событие";
        }
    }
}
```

//Здесь я вывожу рандомное событие, можно ли как то лучше написать этот код?

Comment: В `$rand==1` опечатка, полагаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример: [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a17e684617ca32ffde6ae656f62f80a85b7764e2)

```
<?php

$msg = 'пример сообщения';

if($msg !== 'пример сообщения')
    return;

//if($user->messages == 0)
//    return;

$texts = array("первое событие", "второе событие", "третье событие");
$chance = rand(0, count($texts) - 1);
echo $texts[$chance];


echo "\n";

$switch_chance = rand(1, 5);

switch($switch_chance) {

    case 1:
        echo 'первое событие';
        break;
    case 2:
        echo 'второе событие';
        break;
    case 3:
        echo 'третье событие';
        break;

    default:
        echo 'событие не найдено';
        break;
}
```

Не плодите бургер в виде if'ов, это ухудшает читабильность.

**@Эникейщик** посоветовал вам решить задачу через массив с событиями или через **switch**.

Я просто дал более подробный ответ.

Comment: то есть лучше создать дополнительную хеш-таблицу в виде массива ))) вы конечно меня извините но вы посмотрите как работают хеш-таблицы внутри php и вы перестанете злоупотреблять этим типом данных для минимальных потребностей..

Comment: @noname2019 а что за претензии к массивам в пхп? поделитесь линками для чтения.

Comment: @teran претензий нет. есть факт что использование массивов явно на порядок больше жрёт процессорных действий и памяти чем строковая переменная. а линки думаю лучше чем гитхаб исходников php не найти... смотря к кому или чему делать гуманным код, если к читателю то да лучше может и массив, если к ресурсам то навряд это лучшее решение

Comment: @noname2019 в случае строковых ключей, я бы и согласился, что это более затратно, но для 0-индексированных массивов вряд ли разница будет хоть как-то заметна. но, опять таки, линки с тестами приветствуются

Comment: @teran если вы не ощущаете разницы между одной одной проверкой на тип и кучей проверок на то какие именно данные могут лежать в массиве, при его инициализации с проверкой на кучу типов для каждого ключа и значения то нам не о чем здесь говорить))

Comment: @noname2019 , а в чем собственно проблема? Я взял за основу ответ Эникейщика и с рабочим примером и ссылкой на сандбокс приправил ответ. Для меня вариант со **switch** выглядит более правильнее, чем вариант с массивом.

Comment: Та проблемы вовсе нет. MoloF вы меня извините и @teran также, если что не так... я просто сказал своё мнение относительно решения с массивами.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать `switch`, например.

Если же нужно просто вывести разный текст, то можно тексты положить в массив и выводить по индексу:

```
$texts = array("первое событие", "второе событие", "третье событие");
```

И потом

```
echo $texts[chance-1];
```

Comment: а лучше `[null, "первое", ...]` или `[1 => "первое", "второе"..]` чтобы не было никаких `-1`

Comment: @teran да лучше случайное число брать из диапазона 0-2, но я так сделал, потому что в вопросе 1-3.